# thymeleaf UTF8 xml bug?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, thymeleaf

I am doing a very simple replacement on an XML template below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<note>  
    <to>
        ARABIC: [[${TEST_AR}]]
        HEBREW: [[${TEST_HE}]]  
        CHINESE (MANDARIN): [[${TEST_CH}]]
    </to>
</note>
```

But it seems like thymeleaf has a UTF8 xml bug, Or Im missing something.
Here is what I tried so far:

- Template is coded in UTF-8
- Java source code is saved in UTF-8
- encoding for OutputStreamWriter is UTF-8
- ClassLoaderTemplateResolver is set to UTF-8    Maven is set to UTF-8
- project.build.sourceEncoding UTF-8
- coded the XML as UTF-8

[image: java encoding]

Seems like Thymeleaf wont write UTF-8 text correctly to XML.
The code example below work faultlessly (except Chinese not sure why but its not import atm) as long as I am opening a **text** template (just the file extension) .

If I use this line , It works ok and output UTF-8 no Issues.

```
 templateEngine.process("test_template.txt", ct,out);
```

works great:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<note>  
    <to>
        ARABIC: كتابة مفهومة من قبل اغل
        HEBREW: ניסיון  
        CHINESE (MANDARIN): 
    </to>
</note>
```

Once I modify this line (and rename the template accordingly)  to this:

```
templateEngine.process("test_template.xml", ct,out);
```

thymeleaf will crap out the Uincode fonts and export them as HEX representation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<note>  
    <to>
        ARABIC: &#x643;&#x62a;&#x627;&#x628;&#x629; &#x645;&#x641;&#x647;&#x648;&#x645;&#x629; &#x645;&#x646; &#x642;&#x628;&#x644; &#x627;&#x63a;&#x644;
        HEBREW: &#x5e0;&#x5d9;&#x5e1;&#x5d9;&#x5d5;&#x5df;  
        CHINESE (MANDARIN): 
    </to>
</note>
```

Full isolated working example just create the template (test_template.txt) and put it under src/main/resources

```
package com.xerox;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

public class TestThymeleafUTF8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
               TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
                ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
                resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");     
                resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
                templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
                Context ct = new Context();             
                ct.setVariable("TEST_AR", "كتابة مفهومة من قبل اغل");
                ct.setVariable("TEST_HE", "ניסיון");
                ct.setVariable("TEST_CN", "王明是中国人。");
                ct.setVariable("currentDate", LocalDateTime.now().toString());
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("test_output.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            
                templateEngine.process("test_template.txt", ct,out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xerox</groupId>
  <artifactId>testUTF</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>testUTF</name>
  <description>thymeleaf testUTF</description>
  
    <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>   
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Not sure this will work or not, but have you tried changing your `TemplateMode` to be xml?  `resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode. XML);` or `resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode. VALIDXML);`

Comment: Thank you, Yes, I tried...  it doesn't matter.

Comment: Not an answer - just an observation: The XML at the start of the question is not valid. There is a non-breaking space in the prolog here: `<?xml version`. I don't think that has anything to do with the problem, though. (I noticed when I validated the XML, copy-pasted from the question.) If there is one NBSP, there may be more.

Comment: I mean, that output is valid and correct XML (if you view the file in something that parses the xml like a browers or whatever), but I do agree that it's weird to encode everything like that if it doesn't have to.  Does whatever you are using the read the output not work with those encoded characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a bug, but the programmed behavior.

The [`setTemplateMode` documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.1.0.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/AbstractConfigurableTemplateResolver.html#setTemplateMode(org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode)) indicates:

> Sets the template mode to be applied to templates resolved by this
> resolver.
>
> If template mode patterns (see `setHtmlTemplateModePatterns(Set)`,
> `setXmlTemplateModePatterns(Set)`, etc.) are also set, they have higher
> priority than the template mode set here (this would act as a default).
>
> Note that this template mode also may not be applied if the template
> resource name ends in a known file name suffix: `.html, .htm, .xhtml, .xml,  .js, .json, .css, .rss, .atom, .txt`. If this behaviour needs to be
> overridden so that template name is always applied, the
> `setForceTemplateMode(boolean)` will need to be set.

Note the note that indicates that for a well known file name suffix the template mode will be overwritten. That explains the behavior you are facing: when you use `test_template.xml` Thymeleaf will no longer use `TemplateMode.TEXT` as configured but `TemplateMode.XML` instead, and the text will be then [escaped](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/39b945b881ffed403ddf37f2c2d022db5b1d2724/lib/thymeleaf/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/standard/processor/StandardTextTagProcessor.java#L113-L131).

As advised in the aforementioned javadoc, you can force Thymeleaf to obbey the configured `TemplateMode` and your desired behavior using [`setForceTemplateMode`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.1.0.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/AbstractConfigurableTemplateResolver.html#setForceTemplateMode(boolean)):

```java
package com.xerox;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

public class TestThymeleafUTF8 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
      ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
      resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
      resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT); // TemplateMode.HTML should work as well
      resolver.setForceTemplateMode(true);
      templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
      Context ct = new Context();
      ct.setVariable("TEST_AR", "كتابة مفهومة من قبل اغل");
      ct.setVariable("TEST_HE", "ניסיון");
      ct.setVariable("TEST_CH", "王明是中国人。");
      ct.setVariable("currentDate", LocalDateTime.now().toString());
      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("test_output.xml"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

      templateEngine.process("test_template.xml", ct,out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: setForceTemplateMode    --- bingo!

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
resolver.setForceTemplateMode(true);
```

note: there is a feature named `smart template mode resolution based on template resource name` and it is active by default

Comment: this is thymeleaf  in Java not Spring boot    so 

The method setContentType(String) is undefined for the type ClassLoaderTemplateResolver

setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  - already there.

Comment: you're right, the answer is corrected